# Should new board games be self contained in the post?

Tags: discussion

I noticed this site is mostly dominated by MTG posts, which obviously do not contain the explanation of how to play it, since it is well known.

But if I were to post a question regarding strategies for a new board game (there is obviously no tag for this particular game), should the post before everything contain as much detail as possible about the rules and gameplay, or should I simply link first thing, to the rule sheets and a gameplay video, and proceed with the question?

Comment: In actual fact: of the site's [8,056 total questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions), only [2,547](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) are MTG. It certainly has more questions than any other tag though, and has almost 9x the questions of the next most popular tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just go right ahead and ask about your question, and make sure to name which game it is.

Including tons of extraneous rules about the game and gameplay would only act to obscure your actual question, so leave that stuff out. We encourage questions to focus exclusively on the pertinent details, and the Stack Exchange network has a practice of cutting out things like signatures, salutations, and unnecessary backstory. If you did include all those details, they'd probably just get removed by an editor (such as me).

Anyone who's answering your question should already own the game and be a player who understands it well. Such a person doesn't need the game explained to them.

Anyone else can google the game if they feel they've got a decent chance of answering it anyway despite not having played it. That's a risky move and not something we necessarily encourage since it's difficult to have confidence in an answer like that and they can just easily be totally wrong.

Comment: Another option is to just include a link to the official site, BoardGameGeek, or something similar. That will give them enough information to understand the game and seek out more information (e.g. online copies of the rulebooks) to answer the question if desired.